# Laravel Cashier/Billing Add multiple items in charge

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-5.7, laravel-cashier

I have a shopping cart, and I am to add multiple products in an order to `charge` method. I am using the below code for making payment of a order:

```
         $user->charge($cart_total, [
            'description' => "Order #12",
            'shipping' =>  [
                'name' => 'Customer Name',
                'address' => [
                    'line1' => '1234 Main Street',
                    'city' => 'Your city',
                    'state' => 'state',
                    'postal_code' => '94111',
                    'country' => 'US',
                ],
            ]
        ]);
```

After this when I check Stripe backend I am seeing the receipt as in below image
I would like to list the items also in below receipt as Items X quantity in summary.

[image]

Comment: The summary is items text comes from the description you set. What you could do is during charge creations, set the description to 'description' => "Product A x 10 (Order #12)",

Comment: @wsw it will not work, I will need to set each items in different lines:
 Item 1 - quantity x unit price = item total
etc

and display the total amount at last.

Comment: I am afraid that is not possible for now. what you could do to work around this might be that, 1) Create a invoice with invoices items 2) You pay the invoice with the customer's card In this case, the receipt will contains well formatted items list. 
https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/create

Comment: @wsw I already tried with invoice items and invoice. It gives expected results.